# 2 different django User models

Tags: python, django, django-models

i have 2 different django User models, one for the clients and one for the admins, The reason for this was that I didn't want the two types of users to be mixed in one model. But I have a problem logging in for the clients users, I can't match their password with each other in View, because the password is saved as hash, but the password that they enter is the same password that they choose to register.

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        try:
            user = CustomUsers.objects.get(email=email, password=password)
        except CustomUsers.DoesNotExist:
            user = None
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserLoginForm
    return render(request, 'CustomUsers/login.html', {'form': form})
```

i tried many ways but i couldent get anything... any solution...? also another question, Will I have trouble later to hiding the registry phrase in the Template when they are logged in? Or also can use {% if.is_authenticated %} again.

Comment: using multiple User Models sounds like a real bad idea... just extend your Model with roles to use `is_staff` or `is_superuser` etc...

Comment: yes its make sense, ill try, thanks for reply btw